# Loop through table using jQuery, update specific cell in a row with a checked Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I just can't work this one out.  I have a table with a column of checkboxes.  After an Ajax update, I want to update a specific cell in the rows with checked checkedboxes.  The jQuery Ajax call I'm using is:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ProcessDate',
        data: params,
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               alert(xhr.statusText);
          },

         success: function(html) {
                  closeDialog();
                  $('#results tbody tr').each(function(){
                         $("#CaseID:checked").parent().siblings("td.DateUpdated").html('CHANGE'); 
            });
        },
        cache: false
     });
```

And the HTML is:

```
<table id="results">
  <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" id="CaseID"></td>
     <td id="DateUpdated"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" id="CaseID"></td>
     <td id="DateUpdated"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" id="CaseID"></td>
     <td id="DateUpdated"></td>
  </tr>
```

The Ajax call succeeds but my table update doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use classes since Ids must be unique, like this:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="CaseID"></td>
  <td class="DateUpdated"></td>
</tr>
```

Then use class selectors, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'ProcessDate',
  data: params,
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.statusText);
  },
  success: function(html) {
    closeDialog();
    $(".CaseID:checked").parent().siblings("td.DateUpdated").html('CHANGE'); 
  },
  cache: false
});
```

There's no need for a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop, at least not with your example code...the class selector will get all the elements you want, regardless of the row.

Comment: OK - IDs changed to classes.  each() loop removed.  Still no change in the html.

Comment: Could the parents().siblings syntax be incorrect?  Am I pointing to the right area?  Do I need the parents() selector?

Comment: @Wendy - Are you sure your callback is successful and the code is running? It works, you can test here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/cBLQL/ It sounds like something *else* is blowing up before it gets there, are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Callback is successful.  No errors in the console.  I'll keep looking for whatever it is that is blowing up.  Thanks for the help - at least I know this syntax will work.

Comment: Doh!  My version here is a bit more complex than the example I gave you.  The <td> I'm looking to change is further down the DOM.  The code above is correct for my example.  For my version, I had to look further, so its  "$(".CaseID:checked").parent().siblings.find("td.DateUpdated").html('CHANGE');

Comment: @Wendy - Ah, yes if the HTML's different the answer is as well :)